# Spring Batch testing - Autowired bean is null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, mockito, spring-batch

I am completely stumped.  I am new to Spring Batch testing and I have found countless examples that have left me confused.

I'm trying to test a Spring Batch decider.  This decider checks to see if certain JSON files exist before continuing.

To begin, I have a **BatchConfiguration** file marked with @Configuration in my Spring Batch project.

In the BatchConfiguration, I have a **ImportJsonSettings** bean which loads its properties from settings in the **application.properties** file.

```
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="jsonfile")
    @Bean
    public ImportJSONSettings importJSONSettings(){
        return new ImportJSONSettings();
    }
```

When running the Spring Batch application, this works perfectly.

Next, here are the basics of the **JsonFilesExistDecider** , which Autowires a FileRetriever object...

```
public class JsonFilesExistDecider implements JobExecutionDecider {

    @Autowired
    FileRetriever fileRetriever;

    @Override
    public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) { ... }
```

The **FileRetriever** object itself Autowires the **ImportJSONSettings** object.

Here is the FileRetriever...

```
@Component("fileRetriever")
public class FileRetriever {

    @Autowired
    private ImportJSONSettings importJSONSettings;

    private File fieldsFile = null;

    public File getFieldsJsonFile(){
        if(this.fieldsFile == null) {
            this.fieldsFile = new File(this.importJSONSettings.getFieldsFile());
        }
        return this.fieldsFile;
    }
}
```

Now for the test file.  I am using Mockito for testing.

```
public class JsonFilesExistDeciderTest {
    @Mock
    FileRetriever fileRetriever;
    @InjectMocks
    JsonFilesExistDecider jsonFilesExistDecider;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
    @Test
    public void testDecide() throws Exception {
        when(fileRetriever.getFieldsJsonFile()).thenReturn(new File(getClass().getResource("/com/files/json/fields.json").getFile()));

        // call decide()... then Assert...
    }
}
```

PROBLEM... The **ImportJSONSettings** object that is @Autowired in the **FileRetriever** object is always NULL.

When calling the **testDecide()** method, I get a NPE since calling the **getFieldsJsonFile()** in FileRetriever, the **ImportJSONSettings** bean does not exist.

How does the **ImportJSONSettings** bean get properly created in the **FileRetriever** object so it can be used??

I have tried adding the following to my test class, but it does not help.

```
@Mock
ImportJSONSettings importJSONSettings;
```

Do I need to create it independently?  How does it get injected into the FileRetriever?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your test run with SpringRunner? Do you have a test application context so that those bean get properly injected? If it's not the case you need to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `@Before` annotation on the `setup()` method to `@BeforeEach` like so:

```
@BeforeEach
void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

This could also be a dependency issue. Make sure you have a recent version of `io.micrometer:micrometer-core`. Would you be able to share your test dependencies?

If you have the above setup correctly, you shouldn't have to worry about whether or not `ImportJSONSettings` is null or not as long as you have `getFieldsJsonFile()` stubbed correctly.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment about stubbing the method.  The test should use the "getFieldsJsonFile()" in the FileRetriever...correct?   In order to do this the "importJsonSettings" object must not be null.

Comment: When you run `when(fileRetriever.getFieldsJsonFile()).thenReturn(new File(getClass().getResource("/com/files/json/fields.json").getFile()));`, you are stubbing the `getFieldsJsonFile()` method. As a result, the implementation of that method should no longer matter, and that method should only return what is in the `thenReturn(new File(getClass().getResource("/com/files/json/fields.json").getFile()))`. Are you sure that `getClass().getResource("/com/files/json/fields.json").getFile())` isn't the source of the NPE? Also make sure you are using JUnit and Mockito for all the annotations.